# program running on max osx normally and in linux abnormally

Tags: c, linux, macos

i have been really busy with a project on operating systems recently .. i am working on my macs and everything is going great..when i tried to run the same programm at a pc running linux the programm went terribly wrong...for example fgets and fscanf work fluently at mac but when i try to fgets 2 times in a row from stdin(rewinding the stdin firstly) i dont get what i want on linux even though at my mac evertyhting is running normally as expexted..please help me if i am missing out any information about linux and problems..

```
void add_new_account(int sd)
{
    int my_id, next_id;
    struct drivers instance; 

    read(sd, &next_id, sizeof(int));
    if (next_id >= 1000) {
        printf("system is full .. we are sorry for this inconvenience\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    rewind(stdin);
    fgets(instance.driver_name, sizeof(instance.driver_name), stdin);

    rewind(stdin);
    fgets(instance.password, sizeof(instance.password)+1, stdin);

    write(sd, &instance, sizeof(instance));
    read(sd, &my_id, sizeof(int));
    printf("your unique id is %d! please save it in order to login with it\n", my_id);
}
```

Comment: Post some code please or we'll just have to guess.

Answer (score 4):

You should not rewind `stdin`, since it's not guaranteed to work.  It's impossible to say exactly what's happening without seeing any code, but I'm guessing you're trying to rewind `stdin` with [`fseek`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) (or one of its kin such as [`fsetpos`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) or [`rewind`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek)) and that call is failing.

Regular file objects are seekable, but other types of file-like objects such as sockets and FIFOs are usually not seekable.  In your limited case, you're probably observing that Mac OS X is buffering enough data for you to seek it to your liking, but Linux is not doing so.

You should rewrite your program so that you don't need to rewind `stdin`.  The way you'd do this is by doing your own buffering—read data into a buffer in your application, and then read data out of that buffer (possibly multiple times, if necessary).  Then you don't need to depend on the input stream being rewindable.

Comment: void add_new_account(int sd)
 {
  int my_id,next_id;
  struct drivers instance;
  read(sd,&next_id,sizeof(int));
  if(next_id>=1000)
  {
   printf("system is full .. we are sorry for this inconvenience\n");
   exit(0);
  }
  read(sd,buf,sizeof(buf));
  printf("%s\n",buf );
  rewind(stdin);
  fgets(instance.driver_name,sizeof(instance.driver_name),stdin);
  rewind(stdin);
  fgets(instance.password,sizeof(instance.password)+1,stdin);
  write(sd,&instance,sizeof(instance));
  read(sd,&my_id,sizeof(int));
  printf("your unique id is %d! please save it in order to login with it\n",my_id);
 }

Comment: this is an example of how used rewind with stdin..well the first fgets works normally but the second one not even asks for input..thanks for your help..i just tried though running it without rewind on my mac and it has the same problem like linux...